# How access uploaded file in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am new to Spring framework in spring site There is tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ that upload file to the root folder "upload-dir" (this folder is beside src root folder)

questions:

1. How can I access and show image in browser (or access it in thymeleaf by th:src="@{}" syntax) - 
   by browsing to localhost:8080/files/first.jpg because of controller it give me download link.
2. should I always upload file to folder that beside src folder for example I want to upload file to "src/main/resources/static/file" is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

When accessing files in your code, Spring will (by default) assume that the *src/main/resources* is the parent directory. If you are planning on accessing the files that are uploaded, then I would use *src/main/resources* (or a subdirectory of this location) as the upload path. This way, you can simply access them in Thymeleaf as such:

```
Location: src/main/resources/picture.jpg
Thymeleaf: th:src="@{picture.jpg}"
```

Or if the file exists in a subdirectory:

```
Location: src/main/resources/somedir/picture.jpg
Thymeleaf: th:src="@{somedir/picture.jpg}"
```

If you are storing the file(s) elsewhere, then you can also access them using various prefixes like *classpath* or *file*, i.e.:

```
classpath:com/myapp/config.xml
```

See more about Resources in Spring here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: `src/main/resources` only exists development time and is actually part of the class path. You can only upload to external paths not paths internal to the application.